# How do wearables track exercises without taking input from user?

Tags: microcontroller, accelerometer, android, gyro, wearable

Recently there have been [wearable devices](https://www.atlaswearables.com/product/) that can track your exercises and reps (eg bench press, push ups, pull ups) without the user telling them. What technology do they use to track these exercises?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you gave clearly indicates the sensors that are used:

> SENSORS
>
> 3-axis Accelerometer
>
> 3-axis Gyroscope
>
> Optical Heart Rate Sensor

The manufacturer  will use algorithms to attempt to model the exercises from the motion (as sensed by the inertial sensors) and heart rate (from the optical heart rate sensor), and from other information you do tell it such as body mass.

A typical smart phone would have the inertial sensors, but not the heart rate sensor, so an external device of some kind would be required to use a smart phone.